# Using EXTRACT YEAR, EXTRACT MONTH and CONCAT functions to get the date in "Month Name, YYYY" format

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a MySQL table named `Student` which has a column named `entry_date` of type `date`. I want to select the `entry_date` in the following form:

```
November, 2014
```

i.e. it will show the name of the month and the year portion of the column `entry_date`. As per MySQL standards, I have used the following: `EXTRACT MONTH FROM entry_date`, then `EXTRACT YEAR FROM entry_date`, and then concatenate them both using the `CONCAT` function.

I have written the following `JOIN` query where I tried to do the above:

```
SELECT s.std_id AS id, s.std_name AS name, 
CONCAT(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM s.entry_date), ',' , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s.entry_date)) AS entry_date
d.dept_name AS department, h.house_name AS house
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN department d
ON d.id = s.std_dept
LEFT JOIN house h
ON h.id = s.std_house
```

I'm getting the results, no problem with that, but the results of `entry_date` is in the following format:

`11, 2014`

Which means it is returning the month digit instead of the month name.

Whereas, I want it in this format : `November, 2014`

How can I get the `entry_date` in the second format in MySQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(entry_date),", ", YEAR(entry_date)) as formatted_date
```

the result for **formatted_date** field would something like **November, 2014**

Answer (score 7):

Use the following function. No need of concat or extract.

```
           DATE_FORMAT(entry_date,'%M,%Y') as entry_date
```

| Format | Description |
| --- | --- |
| %a | Abbreviated weekday name (Sun to Sat) |
| %b | Abbreviated month name (Jan to Dec) |
| %c | Numeric month name (0 to 12) |
| %D | Day of the month as a numeric value, followed by suffix (1st, 2nd, 3rd, ...) |
| %d | Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31) |
| %e | Day of the month as a numeric value (0 to 31) |
| %f | Microseconds (000000 to 999999) |
| %H | Hour (00 to 23) |
| %h | Hour (00 to 12) |
| %I | Hour (00 to 12) |
| %i | Minutes (00 to 59) |
| %j | Day of the year (001 to 366) |
| %k | Hour (0 to 23) |
| %l | Hour (1 to 12) |
| %M | Month name in full (January to December) |
| %m | Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12) |
| %p | AM or PM |
| %r | Time in 12 hour AM or PM format (hh:mm:ss AM/PM) |
| %S | Seconds (00 to 59) |
| %s | Seconds (00 to 59) |
| %T | Time in 24 hour format (hh:mm:ss) |
| %U | Week where Sunday is the first day of the week (00 to 53) |
| %u | Week where Monday is the first day of the week (00 to 53) |
| %V | Week where Sunday is the first day of the week (01 to 53). Used with %X |
| %v | Week where Monday is the first day of the week (01 to 53). Used with %x |
| %W | Weekday name in full (Sunday to Saturday) |
| %w | Day of the week where Sunday=0 and Saturday=6 |
| %X | Year for the week where Sunday is the first day of the week. Used with %V |
| %x | Year for the week where Monday is the first day of the week. Used with %v |
| %Y | Year as a numeric, 4-digit value |
| %y | Year as a numeric, 2-digit value |

Comment: Although Elias' answer provided me the solution, this is perfect too. Great solution. So, +1. :)